# How do we get the bluetooth name of altbeacon?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, altbeacon

The altbeacon library(refer link below) says that bluetooth name of a beacon is transmitted separately from advertisement data. How do we get this data?
Also, is any any way to send data tags(small key-value pairs) via beacon?

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/Beacon.java#L149

EDIT : beacon.getBluetoothName() doesn't work, it returns null, as it should.